# Lisp: Having Trouble with Conditionals

Tags: common-lisp

Hey guys I am just starting to learn Lisp at my university however the professor is incredibly poor and does not seem to know the language himself so I turn to you all. I am very experienced in Java and am having trouble relating the conditionals of Java to Lisp. Here is the problem I am asked to solve.

"Write a function which takes the age of the passenger and the amount of airfare between two cities. If the child is less than two the airfare is 0, between two and five it is 60 percent of the full fare. If the child is five or older they full fare."

Here is my solution that worked, but I feel like this is inefficient.

```
(defun young-child(x y)
        (cond
          ((< x 2) 0)
          ((= x 2) (* y .6))
          ((= x 3) (* y .6))
          ((= x 4) (* y .6))
          ((= x 5) (* y .6))
          ((> x 5) y)))
```

Now in Java I simply would have said

```java
if (x >= 2 && x =< 5) {
  return y*.6
}
else if (x < 2) {
  return 0;
}
else {
  return y;
}
```

What I am asking is this: Is there a better way to write this Lisp conditional? If I had to check for a larger range of ages then the code would get incredibly tedious using this method. Is there a way in Lisp to check for 2 conditions within one if statement like I did above in Java? Thank you so much for looking over this code and for any future responses!

Comment: Why would you think that Lisp doesn't have an operator corresponding to Java's `&&`?

Comment: I just wasn't sure as they are different paradigms. I have not had experience with the functional paradigm and have only been coding in Lisp for a week. I figured it wasn't going to hurt to ask. Thanks for the response.

Comment: This is a fun way to learn some Lisp: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HM1Zb3xmvMc

Comment: Just a note:  for readability, even in Java, you might prefer `2 <= x && x <= 5`.  It's not quite the way we'd *pronounce* it in English, but it looks a lot more like the mathematical condition **2 ≤ x ≤ 5**, and you can do `(<= 2 x 5)` in Lisp.  But even in Java, it's a bit redundant.  In Java you can do `if (x < 2) {} else if (x <= 5) {} else {}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lisp has an `AND` operator that can be used to combine multiple conditions.

```
(defun young-child (x y)
  (cond ((and (>= x 2) (<= x 5)) (* y .6))
        ((< x 2) 0)
        (t y)))
```

You can also do it with a single function call `(<= 2 x 5)` or `(>= 5 x 2)` to test if `x` is between `2` and `5` inclusive.

But if you test `(< x 2)` first, you don't need to test whether `(>= x 2)` after that, since conditions are tested in the order given.

```
(defun young-child (x y)
  (cond ((< x 2) 0)
        ((<= x 5) (* y .6))
        (t y)))
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for posting this. This is incredibly informative. One small question I have is what is (t y) that you place at the end of your conditionals? Sorry I have only been using Lisp for about a week now.

Comment: That's the `else` clause. `T` is a constant that's always true.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks again!

Comment: Alternatively, use `(< x 2)` and (> x 5)` as the explicit tests and then `(t (* y .6))`.

Answer (score 0):

Also possible:

```
(defun young-child (age fare) 
  (* (con ((< age 2) 0) 
          ((< age 5) .6)
          (t 1)) 
     fare)
```

Functional programming makes it possible :) .